# How to hide one's public IP when they serve a website

Tags: networking, ip, internet

When people use their home computer to host a website, what are some ways to hide their public IP? if there are any. Sure, it can't be completely hidden for everyone, like my IPS.

Does cloudflare work as CDN help in this case?

Any way to hide the public IP for normal site visitors?

Comment: welcome - there are many, many options for achieving the end-goal of putting a service or information on the internet, which simply makes your q as it stands far too broad (and also, probably off-topic for this site) - some concepts you may wish to follow up on: [tunneling](https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling), cloudflare/ argo tunnel, ssh reverse tunnels, reverse proxying

Comment: This sounds like an X Y problem.  Let me start with the basic part, why would you want to hide your IP at all? What is the goal?